# Is there a way to stop printing "None" if the xml section is not found in the xml

Tags: python, excel, xml, python-3.x

my code reads from the xml file and print into separate columns in excel sheet but if the xml section isn't found it prints None is there a way to print nothing like a empty cell.

```
i=1
for entry in listOfFiles:


    if fnmatch.fnmatch(entry, pattern):

            full_file = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(entry))
            dom = ElementTree.parse(full_file)
            courses = dom.findall('DISS_authorship')
            for c in courses: 

                author_fname = c.find('DISS_author/DISS_name/DISS_fname').text
                author_mname = c.find('DISS_author/DISS_name/DISS_middle').text
                author_lname = c.find('DISS_author/DISS_name/DISS_surname').text
                email = c.find('DISS_author/DISS_contact/DISS_email').text

                sheet1.write(i, 5, '%s' % author_fname)     
                sheet1.write(i, 6, '%s' % author_mname)
                sheet1.write(i, 7, '%s' % author_lname)
                sheet1.write(i, 8, '%s' % email)
                i += 1
```

Comment: if `something == None: sheet1.write("")`?

Comment: `author_fname = c.find('DISS_author/DISS_name/DISS_fname').text or ""`

Comment: @Axois `if something is None:` or just `if something:`.

Comment: @KlausD. May i know whats the difference?